# Random space beneath website footer

Tags: css, wordpress, whitespace, margin

Can anyone else explain the random white space behind the footer of this website (http://rasa-wakefield.org.uk/wp/)?

Thanks

Comment: Care to elaborate? Which browser? What do you mean by random, does it only happen sometimes? It looks fine in the latest Chrome.

Comment: Random as in, I haven't intentionally coded it. I have seen it on Firefox and Chrome and it is always there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `#foot` to `height: auto;` and you're fine. Or just remove the height.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file (http://rasa-wakefield.org.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/rasa/css/css.css) you have:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #526b7f;
    color: #FFF;
    border-top: 5px solid #123056;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

and

```
#foot {
    clear: both;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #526b7f;
}
```

Those "height: 200px" are the cause.